# Octopress transparent images have backgrounds

Tags: css, png, octopress

I'm creating a website using Octopress. When I added a transparent PNG to a webpage, it came up with a white background. I've used the same PNG on a previous site, and it showed transparent.

I can add the image using either basic html image tag or Octopress' image tag.

```
{% img [class names] /path/to/image [width] [height] [title text [alt text]]
```

An example is http://aradreed.me/404. I've turned the border off on the preview, but not the live site yet. I've tried using css to fix the issue by doing `background: transparent;` and other versions of that, but the background is still there. Is there any way I can have the transparency of the image preserved on my website?

Comment: jsFiddle/snippet/website link?

Comment: are you referring to the trash.png image which has a border around it?

Comment: It is transparent, but you are displaying it against a white background, which probably comes from your screen.css which specifies a background image.

Comment: The issue was already solved. It was transparent, but the CSS added a box shadow to it, which I had mistaken for an image background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that image on your website using the developer tools, the image gets the following styles from the `screen.css` stylesheet:

```
article img {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
     -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
     -ms-border-radius: 0.3em;
     -o-border-radius: 0.3em;
     border-radius: 0.3em;
     -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 1px 4px;
     -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 1px 4px;
     box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0 1px 4px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: #fff 0.5em solid;
}
```

Because of these styles, the image gets a white border and a shadow. You can overwrite these styles by placing the following CSS at the bottom of your `screen.css` stylesheet:

```
article img {
     box-shadow: none !important;
     border: none !important;
}
```

I've tested it and it's working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Would you see a simple way to keep the background, excepted for specific images?